# Junit Test in Spring Boot does not inject the service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this service:

```
@Service
public class TdkRestApiService {
    ...
}
```

that I want to test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TdkApplicationConfig.class, TdkDevelopmentConfig.class}) 
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TdkRestApiServiceTests {


    /**
     * The object being tested.
     */
    @Autowired
    TdkRestApiService tdkRestApiService;

    @Test
    public void getCallbacksByDeviceTypeTest () throws IOException {

        tdkRestApiService.getCallbacksByDeviceType("2", "3");

    }
}
```

but I got an error:

```
ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@dd3b207] to prepare test instance [com.tdk.backend.service.TdkRestApiServiceTests@6db9f5a4]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.tdk.backend.service.TdkRestApiServiceTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tdkRestApiService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tdk.backend.service.TdkRestApiService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fix my problem:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes =  TdkApplication.class)
public class SigfoxRestApiServiceTests {
.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here :

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TdkRestApiServiceTests {
```

You don't specify the `classes` attribute of the `ContextConfiguration` annotation.

You should set this attribute with your root Spring configuration class that sets all your configuration and particularly the `TdkRestApiService` bean.
For example if your root Spring configuration class is `MyConfig`, you could specify it :

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TdkRestApiServiceTests {
```

You can have more information on the [Spring documentation discussing of 
detecting test configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config).

Below an extract :

> If you’re familiar with the Spring Test Framework, you may be used to
>   using @ContextConfiguration(classes=…​) in order to specify which
>   Spring @Configuration to load. Alternatively, you might have often
>   used nested @Configuration classes within your test.

Comment: You saved me a ton of head ache <3

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @SpringBootTest to the test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TdkRestApiServiceTests {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat solution by creating a TestConfig.class like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class TestConfig {

}
```

Then, you can add it to your test class with the **@Autowired** components like the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class Test { 

   @Autowired
   private Component component;

}
```

After that, you will be able to use Spring components inside your test class.

Comment: Didn't seem enough somehow, wasn't finding my beans...till I added more like `@Import({ MyClass1.class, MyConfigurationClass2.class }`

Comment: I think it depends on where your classes are located, in my case all classes were in the same base package.