# How does spring boot framework determine which bean is autowired if there are multiple implementations of the said interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm totally new to the concept of spring boot IoC, and @Bean

Let's say this code is implemented

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication{
    @Bean
    public WebClient rest(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clients,
                          ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authz) {
```

You see here, there is only 1 class that implements the interface `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` so my correct guess is if there's only one class that implements it, then that would be automatically `autowired` to the `clients` parameter

```
public final class InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository
        implements ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository, Iterable<ClientRegistration> {
```

---

On the other hand, `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` is implemented by 3 different classes namely

```
public final class AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository
        implements ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository {


public class UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository implements ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository {



public final class WebSessionServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository
        implements ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository {
```

Upon debugging, the class that get picked up is `AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`

How does spring boot framework knows which is which? I think there would be bean conflicts such as in this question [Spring boot autowiring an interface with multiple implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766013/spring-boot-autowiring-an-interface-with-multiple-implementations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `ServerOAuth2AuthroizedClientRepostiry` is an instance of `AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` is because Spring will by default look for a bean that resolves to type `ServerOAuth2AuthroizedClientRepiository` but if one does not exist, a new `AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` object will be created.

If you want to override this you can create a new Bean with the type of your choice.

```java
@Bean
ServerOAuth2AuthroizedClientRepostiry repository() {
    return new WebSessionServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository(...);
}
```

Comment: But there is no qualifier used to choose which one. This is a standard code I got from the docs.

Comment: My apologies, I thought those were custom implementations, i'll edit my post.

Comment: If they're not beans, what/how is Spring injecting them into the `rest` `@Bean` annotated factory method?

Comment: Oh wow yeah it does look like they look for a bean first before falling back on class members.

Comment: Docs for what? The OP has a `MyApplication` configuration class with a `@Bean` factory method.  They claim that method receives a `AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` object. Where is that object coming from if it's not a bean?

Comment: It is coming from ServerHttpSecurity#getAuthorizedClientService() and a new AuthenticatedPricincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedCLeintRepository object is being created from it.

Comment: I saw this part getBeanOrNull(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.class); So technically, it is set up as a Bean. If I want to choose WebSessionServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository instead of AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository, how would I do it in my application context?

Comment: I'll create another answer, one second.