# How to use polymorphism with abstract spring service?

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism, autowired

I have a polymorphic service, like this:

```java
public abstract class PaymentService {
    abstract boolean processPayment(Payment payment);
}
```

```java
@Service
public class CreditPaymentService extends PaymentService {
    @Override
    public boolean processPayment(Payment payment) {
        // method implementation
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class CashPaymentService extends PaymentService {
    @Override
    public boolean processPayment(Payment payment) {
        // method implementation
    }
}
```

And in my PaymentController, i receive a Payment and i must send it to the right service to process it, depending on the type of the payment.

```java
@Controller
public class PaymentController {

    @Autowired
    private PaymentService service;

    @Override
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Payment> processPayment(@RequestBody Payment payment) {
        service.processPayment(payment);
        return noContent().build();
    }
}
```

How would spring know which service to instantiate?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766013/spring-boot-autowiring-an-interface-with-multiple-implementations

Comment: @David Conrad is right.  Also, what's the harm in just injecting the subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be use bean name as follows. This expects a mode of payment specified in the request.

example : `Payment`

```
public class Payment {
    private String mode;

    public String getMode() {
        return this.mode;
    }

    //.. rest of the class
}
```

Now define a constants class `PaymentModes`

```
public final class PaymentModes {
    private PaymentModes() {
    }

    public static final String CASH = "cash";
    public static final String CREDIT = "credit";
}
```

And provide bean names for the services

```
@Service(value = PaymentModes.CASH)
public class CashPaymentService extends PaymentService {

    @Override
    public boolean processPayment(Payment payment) {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

and

```
@Service(value = PaymentModes.CREDIT)
public class CreditPaymentService extends PaymentService {
    @Override
    public boolean processPayment(Payment payment) {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

This would register both the beans to the application context with the bean names specified during component scan.

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-autowire)

> An autowired Map instance’s values consist of all bean instances that
>   match the expected type, and the Map instance’s keys contain the
>   corresponding bean names.

So if you autowire as follows

```
@Autowired
Map<String,PaymentService> serviceMap;
```

the map would be something as follows :

```
{cash=rg.so.q61741320.CashPaymentService@1e74829, credit=rg.so.q61741320.CreditPaymentService@16f416f}
```

where key is the bean name configured and value is the bean instance.

and the following logic can be used to lookup the required service instance from the map.

```
@Override
@PostMapping
private ResponseEntity<Payment> processPayment(@RequestBody Payment payment) {
    String paymentMode = payment.getMode();// get payment mode;
    if(serviceMap.containsKey(paymentMode)) {
        serviceMap.get(paymentMode).processPayment(payment);
    }
    return noContent().build();
}
```

Note : The overridden methods should be `public` to allow it to be called from other classes , but given as `private` in the code with the question. Appears to be a typo .

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't. You have to use a `@Qualifier` and autowire both of them, and then determine which one to dispatch the payment to, presumably by looking in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to this, by using a factory for your paymentServices.

First of all create a factory that will get you the right Service based on **paymentType** (You could also use Enums for this).

Then whenever you want to get a paymentService, you get it through the **factory**.

```
    @Component
    public class PaymentServiceFactory {

        @Autowired
        ApplicationContext context;

        public PaymentService getPaymentService(String paymentType) {

            // paymentType: Could be cash or credit
            return (PaymentService) context.getBean(paymentType + "PaymentService");
        }
    }

    @Controller
    public class PaymentController {
        @Autowired
        PaymentServiceFactory paymentServiceFactory;

        @PostMapping
        private ResponseEntity<Payment> processPayment(@RequestBody Payment payment) {

            PaymentService service = paymentServiceFactory.getPaymentService(payment.type);
            service.processPayment(payment);
            return noContent().build();
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps you.